# displaying current distance

Tags: objective-c, cllocationmanager

I'm trying to obtain the current distance that has been travelled since LocationManager was started. But i'm facing a few issues.

here is the code I have so far:

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {
    if (self.startLocation == nil)
    {
        totalDistanceBetween = 0;
        _startLocation = newLocation;
    }
    CLLocationDistance distanceBetween = [newLocation distanceFromLocation:_startLocation ];
    self.startLocation = newLocation;
    totalDistanceBetween += distanceBetween;
    NSString *cycleDistanceString = [[NSString alloc]
                            initWithFormat:@"%f",
                            totalDistanceBetween];
    _CurrentDistance.text = cycleDistanceString;
}


@end
```

When I run my app my label CurrentDistance is not updated at all. I'm still relatively new to objective-c so not sure where I'm going wrong any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Just a side note: according to Objective-C naming conventions, method and instance variable names, e.g., `_CurrentDistance`, should ordinarily begin with a lowercase letter, so `_currentDistance` would be better.

Answer (score 2):

You should add a log or debug to ensure you are receiving location callbacks. If not, you haven't registered for updates (properly).

If you are getting callbacks then I guess `_CurrentDistance` is an outlet to a label which isn't connected (so you are asking `nil` to do something and nothing happens).

Comment: I've put a log at the end of this method to to print out the array cycleDistanceString, and newLocation and not getting anything back from either. So it looks as though the method is not getting called, but no idea why! Looks OK to me, but i'm still pretty new to Objective-c –

Comment: How and where are you registering for location updates?

Comment: `- (void)startCycleLocation{
    
    if (!_cycleLocation){
        _cycleLocation = [[CLLocationManager alloc]init];
        _cycleLocation.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation;
        _cycleLocation.distanceFilter = 5;
        _cycleLocation.delegate = self;
        _startLocation = nil;
        
        
    }
    [_cycleLocation startUpdatingLocation];` is where I am calling them, which is called on didViewLoad.

Comment: And you're sure that's called?

Comment: Yeah I think so, do you want to see the .m file?

Comment: '- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self startCycleLocation];
    [mapView setDelegate:self];
    self.locations = [NSMutableArray array];
}' is where the method is first called.

Comment: I'd add logging to confirm. Running on a device? Get any callbacks at all? Change the accuracy to maximum. Check the delegate isn't deallocated somehow.